# MapViewDirections Error: Error on GMAPS route request: TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

MapViewDirections Error: Error on GMAPS route request: TypeError: Network request failed keeps coming up every time I try running the app. I need to show a line between 2 points. What could be the problem with this code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions'

const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = '...'
const origin = {
  latitude: 15.846812,
  longitude: 80.89134,
  latitudeDelta: 0.0622,
  longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
}
const destination = {
  latitude: 15.750875,
  longitude: 81.018389,
  latitudeDelta: 0.0622,
  longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
}

class MapSample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      console.log('orgin', { origin }),
      console.log('destination', { destination }),
      (
        <MapView
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 15.846812,
            longitude: 81.018389,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0622,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        >
          <MapViewDirections
            origin={origin}
            destination={destination}
            apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
          />
        </MapView>
      )
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mapContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
    marginTop: 20,
    flex: 1,
  },
  map: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    flex: 1,
  },
})

export default MapSample
```

I created an API key successfully, I do not know why this error message keeps coming.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while programming on a React Native project at work.

The solution for me was to remove any restrictions on the network that I was working on.

Maybe your firewall is restricting you at some point which throws you that error. You could try disabling it.

Comment: Thank you Erick for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this error. The problem was, I had not enable billing on my google account. So activating billing makes it work ok.